# Make a $_SESSION in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, php, session, ember.js

How can you make a session variable in EmberJS like in PHP?

```
$_SESSION['foo']='bar';
```

Comment: Do you even understand that you are on client-side not server-side? If you just want a global store use a service.

Comment: What i mean its is there a way to define variable in wich i can access in all routes ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a service. Create a file `app/services/mysession`. Next do this in your routes, controllers and objects where you want to access the service:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  mysession: Ember.inject.service(),
});
```

next you can just set and access variables on the service:

```
Ember.set(this, 'mysession.foo', 'bar');
Ember.get(this, 'my session.foo'); // returns bar
```

All services are persistent over the entire application lifecycle.